# what is the collector gain of a transistor?

Tags: transistors, current, npn

I was wondering what exactly **collector gain** is for npn transistors, or more specifically if there is some sort of equation for getting it, and if its value changes as you change the input voltage/current. I have searched google for this but I am quite new to transistors and am having a hard time understanding the stuff and understanding what they are talking about.

Comment: Are you referring to the transconductance (gm) or Voltage gain (Av) or Current gain (β)? If you're new, and don't know what these are, you should definitely read enough to understand the difference between these three.

Comment: IOt is vital to know what the question you are asking actually is. The CURRENT GAIN of the transistor is device specific as people have said. The voltage gain of the circuit that the transistor is used in is: For closed loop gain -  circuit dependant. For open loop gain - semiconductor type (Si, Ge, ...) dependant as long as the transistor is not too abnormal. The question MUST be tied down more or you will get a good answer but not know what the question was.

Comment: Collector gain of a common emitter silicon transistor with any emitter resistor bypassed for signal at the frequency of interest = 38.4 x the DC voltage drop across the collector resistor in stable condition. REALLY. So eg a 1 transistor amplifier with a 9V supply cannot have a voltage gain of more than 38.4 x 9 = 346 and in practice a bit less than that and only for very small Vout. If you want 8V peak to peak out the Vdc across Rc ~=  4V and max gain = 38.4 x 4 =~ 154. Not many people know that :-) . | If that sounds bizarre and confusing, it's meant to. Many people will tell you it's ....

Comment: ... rubbish. It's not. Ask eg Dave Tweed or Olin Lathrop, or Wouter or ... .  My point is that while the above makes sense once yuou understand the reasonably understandable underpinnings, when you start out the question MUST be well defined or the magic creeps in and confuses you.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, you forgot to include that the Temp = 25°C for that calculation to be true. And please don't go repeating this off to new people without linking a **FULL** explanation of your math that you use to arrive at that (I've seen you derive it before without taking into consideration temperature). Which means you have to explain V-thermal and how it's an intrinsic property of the transistor material (Vthermal = 0.026V at 25°C for Silicon).

Comment: @Dave  I wot that I forgot not to include anything. Arguably the expression is NEVER true, but that was not the aim. The point was not to post something that was overly useful or intelligible but to highlight that many Dragons lurk beneath the surface and that questions need to be asked with as much explanation re what you are wanting to know as possible. In this case I suspect that the question probably meant something like "What is the AC voltage gain of a bypassed emitter common emitter single stage bipolar amplifier". Bob could have made that clearer but the question was OK. BUT  ....

Comment: .... some of the answers received were dealing with beta which was not what he was wanting. That too is a useful subject and the answers will have their place but they will have added to the confusion. | A **FULL** explanation was the last thing I was wanting in a comment of this sort.

Comment: Yes - I agree to that. "Collector gain" means (I am pretty sure): Voltage gain referenced to the collector node. And the answer is: Gain A=-gm*Rc/(1+gmRe). In this equation the term gm is the transconductance which is determined by the DC quiescent current  gm=Ic/Vt (Vt=temp. voltage of app. 26mV). Re is the signal-effective emitter resistance. The so-called "current gain" has no influence on voltage gain - it determines the signal input resistance only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gain is generally variable in a transistor, based on the Ic, Collector current (Generally Ice to Emitter). It varies by transistor family or part. It can even vary individual parts of the same model number. Manufacturers using the same part number and design will also vary slightly. Like any semiconductor, diode, resistor, etc, no two parts are 100% identical and there is tolerances that apply. A manufacturer will try to minimize the differences, but it's impossible to do completely.

**You'll need to check it's data sheet for Hfe. That is the gain parameter.** Notice that the value will be a typical, or provided as a range of min to max.

This is the stats for a Fairchild 2n3904:
[image]

Gain peaks at 10mA, like a bell curve. At 10mA Ic, it's minimum should be 100 gain, while it's maximum is 300. It may actually be 150 on the part you test. When designing a board, you would want to overdrive it. Use the smallest gain listed as your design spec, instead of the typical or max. That way you can't lose.

There is no fixed formula, as the gain is a property of its design.

Comment: So can gain change per manufacture? Or is it the same value for all of that type of transistor?

Comment: @BobSmith `It can even vary individual parts of the same model number.` The numbers on the data sheet are typical, one 2n3904 may be 100 hfe @ 10mA IC, another may be 300 hfe. And yes, it can change from one manufacturer to another. The Fairchild 2n3904 may be different than the ST 2n3904.

Comment: @Passerby is correct, that's why it's important do design circuits that can work over a wide range of gains.

Comment: Is there a experiment I can do to find the gain?

Comment: Of course, you build a circuit like: http://www.rfcafe.com/references/popular-electronics/images/build-dual-meter-transistor-tester-feb-1960-5.jpg and divide measured collector current by base current. That gives you the current gain. You can also use a ready-made transistor tester. Some multimeters have a transistor test but usually these are cr#p. In professional environments they use a curve tracer or a SPA (Semiconductor Parameter Analyzer).

Comment: @Passerby This answer is (of course) useful (+1) but I think it is not what he was asking abouut. I think he was asking about 1 stage common emitter bipolar voltage gain and not about beta. If he thinks your answer addresses that question he will be more rather than less confused.